# só consigo abrir imagens png com o tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou tentando abrir imagens **jpeg** com o tkinter usando o `PhotoImage`, mas não consigo. O programa e a imagem estão na mesma pasta, mas mesmo assim ele dá erro:

> couldn't open "imagem.jpeg": no such file or directory

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.geometry('1300x740')

imagem = PhotoImage(file="imagem.jpeg")

lb = Label(janela, image = imagem)
lb.place(x = 550, y = 320)`

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pode nos mostrar quais os arquivos que estão no seu diretório em que o arquivo.py principal é executado ?

Answer (score 0):

O PhotoImage do tkinter não trabalhar com todos os formatos de imagem:

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.html

Veja que a documentação ressalta essa parte no seguinte trecho:

> PhotoImage can be used for GIF and PPM/PGM color bitmaps.

---

Quando você tenta abrir uma imagem não suportada pelo PhotoImage do tkinter, a exceção gerada é a seguinte:

> couldn't recognize data in image file "imagem.jpeg"

A sua exceção está distinta dessa, logo você também está tendo problema na localização do arquivo, verifique se a extensão do arquivo na verdade não é `jpg`, é mais comum ser dessa forma.

---

Para trabalhar com um jpg, você pode utilizar da biblioteca PIL (Python Imaging Library):

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Instalando o mesmo pelo pip conforme a documentação orienta:

> python -m pip install pip
>
> python -m pip install Pillow

---

Trabalhando com a PIL, seu exemplo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

janela = Tk()
janela.geometry('1300x740')

jpg = Image.open("imagem.jpeg")
imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(jpg)

# Pode ser tudo em apenas uma linha
# imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage( Image.open("imagem.jpeg") ) 

lb = Label(janela, image = imagem)
lb.place(x = 550, y = 320)

janela.mainloop()
```

---